# Xamarin.Android can't resolve service from a 3rd party library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, here-api

I'm trying to embed HERE maps in a Xamarin application. I was provided an .aar library, which I've bound as a separate project and referenced in my Android project.

According to [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-service.html) I'm supposed to embed an intent service in my app in order to get maps working.

So I've added

```xml
<service
  android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
  android:label="MAPSLABEL"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.my.app.MapsAction">
    </action>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

to `Properties/AndroidManifest.xml`. In my map activity I've added map settings initialization:

```cs
var path = GetExternalFilesDir(null) + File.Separator + ".map_cache";
var success = MapSettings.SetIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(path, "com.my.app.MapsAction"); // returns true
```

Then I call an init on maps fragment like this:

```cs
var f = (SupportMapFragment)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map_fragment);
f.Init(this);
```

And in a callback I receive a `MISSING_SERVICE` error:

```cs
com.nokia.maps.MapServiceClient$c: Map Service Not Found
at com.nokia.maps.MapServiceClient.a(MapServiceClient.java:72)
at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.a(MapsEngine.java:688)
at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.a(MapsEngine.java:393)
at com.here.android.mpa.common.MapEngine.init(MapEngine.java:198)
at com.nokia.maps.bw.a(MapFragmentImpl.java:150)
at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.SupportMapFragment.init(SupportMapFragment.java:112)
at md598e0954ab08e7442f21c9c8f5f40423e.MapActivity.n_onResume(Native Method)
at md598e0954ab08e7442f21c9c8f5f40423e.MapActivity.onResume(MapActivity.java:40)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1363)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7440)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3780)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3845)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3065)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

It seems I can't even locate the service in my code:

```cs
var intent = new Intent("com.my.app.MapsAction");
var result = PackageManager.ResolveService(intent, PackageInfoFlags.Services); // returns null
```

I figured there's probably some mistake in the service declaration, or I'm missing a step or two when trying to declare 3rd-party service in my manifest. Any advice?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you adding the Here SDK to your App?

Comment: Beware that the androidmanifest.xml file gets "merged" at compile time, between the raw file you have in your project, and the various attributes (like ActivityAttribute) in your classes. Are you sure your service xml element does not get overriden after your project is built ? You can check the temporary androidmanifest file generated in the "obj" folder if my memory is correct

Comment: @Cheesebaron, as I said in the question description - I bind an aar library. I'm pretty sure it's bound correctly since I can access necessary fragment, listener and other classes in my activity.

Comment: @Miiite, I can see my service declaration in the generated manifest.

Comment: If you take the generated DLL for the binding library, do you see the classes you expect if you disassemble it i.e. using ildasm or dotPeek or some other disassembler? It might be that your binding library actually didn't produce what you expected.

Comment: It did produce what I expected, I'm debugging the application. A callback is being called, internal HERE checks are being run properly. I don't think HERE api is even relevant to this question.

Comment: @Dmitriy - I am having issues binding the aar library. I am using visual studio 2019 on xamarin as well. Can you let me know how you bound your here sdk? I am running into the same problem as: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43630/xamarin-binding-for-here-maps-problem and there doesn't seem to be any solutions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it usually is the case, the problem was between the chair and keyboard.

When I was adding `service` element to the manifest I was literally adding a `service` element to the `manifest` element. Which is incorrect, your `service`s are to be declared under `application`. So the correct version of the `Properties/AndroidManifest.xml` looks something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.0.0" android:installLocation="auto" package="our_app_package">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="our_app_label">
        <service android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService" android:label="service_label" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="service_action"></action>

            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

It gets merged with other `application` stuff correctly, and the service becomes resolvable.

Thank you @Miiite, for making me triple-check my manifest.